# ¿Como obtener los valores de un array de array?

Tags: c#, array, string

Tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

```
string array = "[["ING","3","6"],["ESP","2","7"]]";
```

Como puedo convertir esa cadena a array para poder obtener los valores de los array que estan dentro de otro array;

He usado `split(',')` pero me separa individualmente cada valor y lo que yo deseo es tener array por array para obtener sus valores

Ejemplo

```
array[0] = ["ING","3","6"];
array[1] = ["ESP","2","7"];
```

y asi poder recorrer sus valores

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para deserializar un `string` utiliza el deserializador genérico `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>` de [`System.Text.Json`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer?view=net-6.0) pasándole el tipo de datos de retorno, en este caso un arreglo de strings de dos dimensiones `string[][]` y la cadena a deserializar:

```
using System.Text.Json;

var arr = @"[[""ING"",""3"",""6""],[""ESP"",""2"",""7""]]";

var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<string[][]>(arr);
```

Aunque en lugar de arreglos, también podrías utilizar listas:

```
var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<List<string>>>(arr);
```

Para trabajar con arreglos de diferentes tipos tienes varias opciones. Puedes hacer tu propio `JsonConverter` (checa [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29695910/deserialize-json-array-with-different-types)) y este [tutorial de Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0).

Otra posible opción es deserializar en un objeto de tipo `JsonElement` y acceder a las propiedades que deseas de la siguiente manera.

```
var json = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(arr);

Console.WriteLine(json[0][0].GetString());
Console.WriteLine(json[1][2].GetInt32());
```

Si la forma del arreglo cambia constantemente esta última opción es la más viable.

Comment: gracias @Jaime Menéndez, una consulta más como declaras un array de diferentes tipos de variables ya que todos los ejemplo que he visto estan de un solo tipo de variable por ejemplo string[], boolean[], etc

Comment: @DarwinUM agregué unas notas sobre ello. Coloqué unas referencias para el uso de `JsonConverter` y una posible solución con `JsonElement`. Una tercera solución es que tu mismo escribas un método para parsear, lo cuál tampoco estaría mal.

Comment: Y si te referias a crear un arreglo en c# estilo javascript con múltiples tipos, me temo que eso no es posible. Lo más que podrás hacer será un arreglo de Objects pero estarás teniendo que hacer casting todo el tiempo para poder usar los valores guardados.

Comment: gracias por tu tiempo.